# dynamic programming filling matrix in sequence alignment

Tags: java, matrix, dynamic-programming, multidimensional-array, sequence-alignment

hello guys i have 2d char array opt[][] and i have 2 sequence in my arrays like in example

my

```
 `opt[0][0]=A        
  opt[0][1]=T
  opt[0][2]=G
  opt[0][3]=A`
```

and

```
 opt[1][0]=A
 opt[2][0]=G
 opt[3][0]=C
 opt[4][0]=T
```

i have this output currently

```
   x/y|  A  T  G  A  -
_______________________
  0 A |  0  0  0  0
  1 G |  0  0  0  0
  2 C |  0  0  0  0
  3 T |  0  0  0  0
  4 - |  0  0  0  0
```

my problem is this how can i use dynamic programming

to create this array into this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViHc9.png

if its a match 0 penalty
if its a mismatch 1 penalty
if its a gap its 2 penalty

i can compare chars of my array like this

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){

                if(opt[0][i]==opt[i+1][0]){

                    result[0][i] =1;

                }
```

but this is just a simple test i made to see if i can compare and it turned out i can.

how can i go from here to there(to the picture array

Comment: How are you getting the output?

Comment: I wouldn't add the letters and numbers into the array.  I would keep them separate as they are in the example table.  I would have a matrix of numbers AND an array of headings either `char` or `String`

Comment: @tintinmj want me to give code?

Comment: @PeterLawrey i can simply erase the letters from output

Comment: If your problem is solved, just accept the answer (or add your own answer, if you solved it yourself). _Do not delete_ solved questions! Solved questions are what makes StackOverflow so great!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read these articles.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm

The implementation in any language is pretty trivial.

And if you need information about dynamic programming in general,
either Google for it yourself, or check these two links.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming
https://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=dynProg&module=Static

Comment: @PeterLawrey His problem is not just the printing. Seems he does not understand the algorithm "my problem is this how can i use dynamic programming"; "but this is just a simple test i made to see if i can compare and it turned out i can".

Comment: It is very unclear what the problem is, but I suspect it's the very basics the OP doesn't know. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I suspect so too. He might need also an article/tutorial on dynamic programming in general.

Comment: op here :) my problem is i can even use some kind of pseudo code i dont know where to start to fill or with what by comparing what??

Comment: @user2560965 That's why I suggested a few good readings for you, so that you know after reading them.

Comment: i read like 10 articles and its still unclear for me but i think i should read 20 more.I can use any help or guideline here